# How to match only alphanumeric with regex

Tags: regex, posix-ere

I'm trying to match alphanumeric with the regex below, but still matched the result that I don't need.

```
([0-9a-z_]+|[0-9a-z]+)
```

What I really want to match are

```
Example:
abc123
abc_123
```

What I don't want to match are

```
Example:
abc
123
123_123
abc_abc
```

Comment: By alphanumeric do you mean that both numbers and letters should exist? This question is unclear.

Comment: @revo yes, and alternative include underscore.

Comment: Are these whole lines or do you plan to extract separate words with something like `grep -oE '...' file`?

Comment: Try `\b_*([0-9]+_*[a-zA-Z]|[a-zA-Z]+_*[0-9])[[:alnum:]_]*\b`

Answer (score -1):

How about perl solution

```
> cat alphanum.txt
abc123
abc_123
abc
123
123_123
abc_abc
> perl -ne ' { print if /\b([a-z]+)|_\b/ and /([0-9]+)/ }' alphanum.txt
abc123
abc_123
>
```

try if this works for you.